# Not clear why my /etc/hosts look like this

Tags: centos, vps

I am bit confuse , my hosts file look like :

```
   > 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain
   > localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
   > 127.0.0.1 autoreply.panel.mywebsite.com
   > 127.0.0.1 myhostname 
   > 127.0.0.1 panel.mywebsite.com
```

why doesn't show the machine Ip address ?? Even so the website is working and the website is accessible from the web.

Anyone can please explain ?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Think of /etc/hosts as a dns system override. You can specify hostnames by IP addresses in this file.

For example you could do the following:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 google.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

And proceed to ping google.com:

```
[jclark@jclark530 ~]$ ping -c1 google.com
PING google.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
```

Your attached server IP address(es) will show by running /sbin/ifconfig